# ASP.Net OLEDB Jet across multiple computers

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, oledb, jet

I am using **Jet OLEDB** (Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0) on my ASP(C#) IIS7 website to connect to an Excel spreadsheet on the same computer/server as my website.  Everything works fine except that the connection string does not like a UNC Path.  It will work with `C:\ThisFolder` but not with `\\MYWEBSERVER01\C$\ThisFolder`.

**Questions:**

Is there a way to use this driver with UNC paths?

Can you use it to connect to Excel files on a different computer (ex: \LABCPC01\C$)? If yes, What does that connection string look like? Are there permission considerations on the other Clients folder (i.e. On the LAB PC)?

What we are attempting is to use a website to capture lab data from multiple lab Excel sheets on multiple lab PCs.  Everything I tried seems to fail when I connect to the client/lab PC.  Has anyone done this before?  What does the connection string look like?

I have searched for a couple of hours and cannot find an answer.

Comment: Are you getting an error with the UNC connection string?

Comment: Yes.  If the connection string is something like \\MYWEBSERVER01\C$\ThisFolder then it does NOT work but if I use C:\ThisFolder on the same server (local to the web server) then it works fine.

Comment: If you are getting an error message, update your post with the content of the message.

Comment: I am not at work right now. I am getting an error that seems like a permissions error from the client PC but I have added the same permissions to the client's folder. I even tried mapping a drive from the webserver as Z:\ThisFolder.  I has not helped.  I can get the exact message later.  Thanks for the quick reply.